# Same android OS version -- one has move to SD card button, the other doesn't

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I have two phones. Both have android OS 4.1.2 installed. Though on one phone it has "Move to SD card" buttons (though some apps have it grayed out), on the other this button does not appear at all. I mounted SD cards on both phones. And the same app would have the button on one phone, not the other.

I have read pages saying android disallowed that at some point. But how come they have it on some apps, not on others?

I loaded Link2SD and use the "move to SD" button there. I got this warning msgs: 
**"Warning: App2SD is not supported by your device. Because your device has a primary external storage which is emulated from the internal storage. you can link the app in order to move its files to your SD card"**

I have little idea what it means. this phone only has 1.24GB of internal storage and it quickly drains.

Two models are Huawei Vitria (which can move to SD card) and LG-LS720 (cannot move to SD card)

Comment: Some phones don't have (external) SD card at all, like Nexus devices, so it's meaningless to move to SD card. Some apps also cannot be moved explicitly to SD card: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27816/unable-to-move-few-apps-to-sd-card

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, but I mounted SD cards on both phones. And the same app would have the button on one phone, not the other

Comment: Which phone models do you have? Can you access the SD card on both phones? This is weird, but I don't have much experience with devices having SD card slot.

Comment: @AndrewT. Huawei Vitria (which can move to SD card) and LG-LS720 (cannot move to SD card)

Comment: It seems it's LG's doing: there are many cases for LG LS720: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83020/move-apps-from-internal-to-sd-android-4-1-2-lge-optimus-f3, http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-optimus-series/323022-optimus-f3-moving-apps-sd.html, http://androidforums.com/threads/moving-apps-to-sd-for-lg-optimus-f3.766839/. For the reason itself, I still don't know, but unless someone knows, it might be hard to get the answer if it's not from LG themselves.

Comment: @AndrewT. I added more info I just dug out -- can you take a look at the edited question?